# Data Integrity Error while loading Gzip Data in Exasol

Tags: database, gzip, importerror, exasol

I am trying to load a gzip file into an Exasol Table but I am getting a data-integrity error while doing so. It is showing "java.sql.SQLException : ETL-5301 : A data integrity error while decompressing the data from start=2 and end=16133(both in bytes) while executing the import statement". Can anybody tell me what is the underlying issue in this case and how can it be resolved ?

I checked the integrity of the gz file using gunzip but it showed no issues. It got decompressed successfully, which means the file is not corrupted as such.

Answer (score 0):

Hari,

Based on the information provided I believe you are experiencing an issue with the internal decompression process during the import.

The first thing I recommend you do is verify your compression method. You need to make sure that the gzip file is compressed using a compatible compression method. Check the Exasol documentation to confirm the supported compression methods: https://docs.exasol.com/home.htm

Also, you should inspect the content of the gzip file to identify any anomalies. It's possible that there are unexpected characters, control characters, or encoding issues that might be causing problems during decompression.

Also, if the file is large, try breaking it into smaller chunks and importing them separately. This can help identify if the issue is related to the file size or if there is a specific portion causing problems.

Other things to consider: Look for any special characters, control characters, or byte sequences that might be causing issues during decompression. These characters might not be visible in a standard text editor. Experiment with different gzip compression parameters (compression level, etc.) to see if changing these parameters resolves the issue. Ensure that the structure of the Exasol table (data types, column order, etc.) matches the structure of the data being loaded. A mismatch in data types or structure could lead to data integrity errors.

I hope this helps!
Kim

Comment: Hi , I checked the documentation in Exasol. They don't provide info regarding the compression method used. I also checked the content of gzip file and couldn't find any anomalies in it.